# list index out of range (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, sum

Trying to experiment around with calculating the sum of a list of integers or floating-points using recursion. However, I am getting a 'list index out of range' error.
Forgive me if this is silly but I am very new to this and still just playing around.

```
def sum(listOfNumbers):
    listOfNumbers == int or float
    if len(listOfNumbers) == 1:
        return listOfNumbers[0]
    else:
        return listOfNumbers[0] + sum(listOfNumbers[1:])


for (input, output) in [ ([1.0], 1), ([1,2], 3), ([1,2.0,3], 6) ]:
    result = 'PASSED' if sum(input) == output else 'FAILED'
    print('Test', input, result)
    print(sum([]))
```

Comment: What do you expect the output of `print(sum([]))` to be? Try to visualize the execution of your function to see what really happens in that case.

Comment: would like the output to be the sum of [1.0], [1,2] and [1,2.0,3]

Comment: As a side note it's not a good idea to name your function `sum` as that's already a part of the standard library.

Comment: Also `listOfNumbers == int or float` line has no effect (although it will almost always evaluate to `float`)

Comment: @JP.Code, I think you're interpreting my question as "what do you expect the output of your entire program to be?", but I was really asking "if you delete the `for (input, output)` line and the the `result = ` line and the `print("test` line, and `print(sum([]))` is the only line remaining outside of the funtion, what do you expect the output to be?" Hint: that is the line that is causing the error.

Comment: thanks for letting me know. I am trying to create a statement where the inputs have to either be an int or float to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing an empty list as a parameter to the `print(sum())` call you are making. Perhaps try passing `input` to see the result of your `sum()` function printed.

Answer (score 0):

Your `sum` function does not work properly when the list has no elements in it. `len(listOfNumbers)` would equal zero, so the `else` clause executes, and tries to access `listOfNumbers[0]`. But a list with no elements doesn't have a zeroth element, so `listOfNumbers[0]` crashes with a "list index out of range" error.

Change your function so it handles lists of length zero. The simplest way to implement this change would be:

```
def sum(listOfNumbers):
    if len(listOfNumbers) == 0:
        return 0
    if len(listOfNumbers) == 1:
        return listOfNumbers[0]
    else:
        return listOfNumbers[0] + sum(listOfNumbers[1:])
```

... But you really only need one base case, so you can remove the middle clause:

```
def sum(listOfNumbers):
    if len(listOfNumbers) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return listOfNumbers[0] + sum(listOfNumbers[1:])
```

Comment: thanks! starting to make sense to me now.
as for the print(sum([])) I am trying to get the total of all the elements